# GridView Image (from URL) to Second Activity by using Intent

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

First of all im giving the codes what i'm using currently

MainActivity

```
    static final String URL = "http://my .com/images/rss.xml";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "item";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
// Click event for single list row
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                     int position, long id) {


                HashMap<String, String> map2 = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullSize.class);
                Bitmap b; // your bitmap

                in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map2.get(KEY_TITLE));
                in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, KEY_THUMB_URL);

                startActivity(in);
             }
         });
```

2nd Activity

```
@Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullsize);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullsizeimg2);
        TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        Intent in = getIntent();
        // Receiving the Data

        String name = in.getStringExtra("item"); 
        Bitmap bitmap =(Bitmap) in.getParcelableExtra("thumb_url");

        // Displaying Received data
        txtName.setText(name);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);




    }
}
```

in this case, if i use the codes as above , the `title` works , i can see the text in txt but i cannot get img. i think i need to convert it to bitmap but also it didnt work for me. for converting bitmap i used this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),"Image ID");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes); 
////////for intent /////
intent.putExtra("imagepass", bytes.toByteArray());
/////////2nd activity//////////
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("imagepass");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

    ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullsizeimg);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

but in main activity after decoderesource line, it was giving this error :
The method decodeResource(Resources, int) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments (Resources, String)

I will be very happy if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using String as the second parameter in BitmapFactory.decodeResource()
But according to your code the Bitmap creation should be like this
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourImageId);

Comment: yes but my IM ID must be drawable , but images coming from internet and not saving by name, they re waiting/staying in cache memory , so with this code i cannot use r.drawable.id because not exist

Comment: for this use the below code..

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);